# Ant - Error running javac.exe compiler

Tags: java, windows, ant, jboss

Pretty green to `Ant` here. I've been running into a problem of trying to get a .jar file to compile in my script (specifically the rt.jar).  I've tried two different ways to fix this (most of which has been found on this site).

Here is how I am setting my path:

```
<path id="build.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${jboss.home}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${jre.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">             
            <include name="**/*.jar" />         
        </fileset>
</path>
```

However, when I try to compile my files with javac using the `fork` attribute:

```
<javac fork="true" includeantruntime="true" debug="on" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${temp.dir.classes}" includes="**/*">             
            <classpath refid="build.class.path" />         
</javac>
```

I get the following error:
[image: error being recieved from using fork]

---

Alternatively, I tried running without the `fork` attribute and get this error:
[image]
Now I know that the file that is not being found is in the `rt.jar`. But it doesn't seem to want to pick it up. I've double checked all of my enviroment variables constantly; even making sure that my JAVA_HOME one isn't pointing to the jre.

Hopefully, I'm just making a newbie mistake but any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### EDIT:

I've been playing around and got older verisons of the JDK and Jboss (both ver 7 now). Now my error is this:
[image]
This is now happening with and without `fork`.

Comment: See you are using the newest version of JDK. Have you tried it with the previous version e.g. 7? It seems that some of the newer libraries are covered by the old ones (coming from the JBoss?).

Comment: Check if the path to your `javac` executable contains spaces. This might create some problems sometimes.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure that missing class is in rt.jar. http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/xml/parser/v2/DOMParser.html

Comment: @peter.petrov Thank you for the help I'm going to try these things and let you know the results! :)

Comment: @Jagger Thank you for the help! I'm going to try that and get back with the results! :)

Comment: OKay, so I checked and no spaces in the path. Going to try and install a previous verison of Java @peter.petrov

Comment: @Jagger So I tried using ver 7 of JDK, didn't seem to work either... :( Thank you though! :)

Comment: The Oracle XML parser package it's complaining about won't be in rt.jar, it'll be something like `xmlparserv2.jar`

Comment: @IanRoberts Hey, I tracked down where that jar was and included it. It works now! Thank you!